# If/Else Bootstrap Pagnation Rule only work on root URL (Express JS / Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, express, if-statement, pug

## The issue

This code works perfectly when visiting Page 1 (first page) and Page 574 (last page), it will block the Previous and Next Buttons to show the start/end of the pagination.

However, when I am sorting under a suburb, the url for the route is not being set to localhost:3000/suburb/x (x being page number), and instead, is just being set to suburb/x for the next and previous buttons on the suburbs pagination.

How can I ensure this pagination works under a suburb?

I am aware this may be to do with my routes not being setup properly... Below is pug code for my Bootstrap Pagination and my App.JS code.

#### JADE (PUG) - index.pug

```
    nav(aria-label='Page navigation example')#pagination
        ul.pagination
            if currentPage == 1
                li.page-item.disabled
                    a.page-link(href='/' tabindex='-1') Previous
                    
            else
                li.page-item
                    if suburb == null
                        a.page-link(href='/' + (currentPage - 1) tabindex='-1') Previous
                    else
                        a.page-link(href='/' + suburb + '/' + (currentPage - 1) tabindex='-1') Previous
            li.page-item.disabled
                a.page-link(href='#')
                    =currentPage
                    |  of 
                    =totalPages
            if currentPage == totalPages
                li.page-item.disabled
                    a.page-link(href= '/') Next
            else
                li.page-item
                    if suburb == null
                        -var count= currentPage
                        -count++
                        a.page-link(href= '/'  + count) Next
                    else
                        -var count= currentPage
                        -count++
                        a.page-link(href= '/' + suburb + '/' + count ) Next
```

#### (JAVASCRIPT)

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

const conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "realestate"
});

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "./public/uploads");
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: { filesize: 1000000 },
    fileFilter: function(req, file, cb) {
        checkFiletype(file, cb);
    }
}).single("myImage");

function checkFiletype(file, cb) {
    const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
    const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
    const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
    if (mimetype && extname) {
        return cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb('Error: Image Only!');
    }
}

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.set("view engine", "pug");
app.set("views", "./views");

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
    res.render('about', {
        title: 'About Us'
    })
});

app.get("/:suburb?/:page?", (req, res)=>{

    let suburb = req.params.suburb;
    let page = req.params.page || 1;
    let limit = 12;
    let offset;
    console.log(suburb);
    console.log(page);
    if (page == 1) {
        offset = 1;
    } else {
        offset = (page - 1) * limit + 1;
    }

    let sqlSuburbs = "SELECT DISTINCT suburb FROM properties ORDER BY suburb";
    let sqlProperties = "SELECT * FROM WHERE suburb = ?";
    let sqlCountPlaceholder = [suburb];
    let sqlCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM properties WHERE suburb = ?";
    let placeholders = [suburb, limit, offset];

    if (suburb == parseInt(suburb)) {
        page = suburb;
        suburb = "";
        offset = (page - 1) * limit + 1;
        sqlProperties = "SELECT * FROM properties";
        placeholders = [limit, offset];
        sqlCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM properties ORDER BY ?";
        sqlCountPlaceholder = [suburb];
    }

    else if (suburb === undefined) {
        sqlProperties = "SELECT * FROM properties";
        sqlCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM properties ORDER BY ?";
        placeholders = [limit, offset];
        sqlCountPlaceholder = ['suburb'];
        suburb = "";
    }
    else
    {
        sqlProperties = "SELECT * FROM properties where suburb = '" + suburb + "'";
        sqlCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM properties where suburb = '" + suburb + "' ORDER BY ?";
        placeholders = [limit, offset];
        sqlCountPlaceholder = [suburb];
    }
    console.log(placeholders);
    console.log(sqlProperties);
    // get the distinct suburbs
    conn.query(sqlSuburbs, (err, suburb_result) => {
        if (err) throw err
        // Get the properties
        conn.query(sqlProperties + " LIMIT ? OFFSET ?", placeholders, (err, properties_result)=>{
            if (err) throw err
            // Get the query record count
            conn.query(sqlCount, sqlCountPlaceholder, (err, record_count)=>{
                var totalPages = Math.ceil(record_count[0].count / limit);
                if (err) throw err

                if(suburb)
                {
                    suburb = '/' + suburb;
                }
                //Display the page and provide it with values
                res.render("index", {
                    title: 'Home Page',
                    suburbs: suburb_result,
                    properties: properties_result,
                    currentPage: page,
                    next: Number(page)+1 > totalPages?totalPages:Number(page)+1,
                    prev: Number(page)-1 >= 1?Number(page)-1:1,
                    totalPages: totalPages,
                    suburb: suburb
                });
            });
        });
    });
});


app.get("/admin/user/dashboard", (req, res)=>{
    res.render('admin/dashboard', {
        title: 'Dashboard'
    });
});

app.get("/admin/user/fileupload", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("admin/uploads", {
        title: 'File Upload Area'
    });
});



app.post("/admin/user/uploads", (req, res)=>{
    upload(req, res, (err)=> {
        if (err) {
            res.render("admin/uploads", {
                msg: err
            });
        } else {
            if (req.file == undefined) {
                res.render("admin/uploads", {
                    title: "File Upload Area",
                    msg: "Error: No File Selected!"
                })
            } else {
                res.render("admin/uploads", {
                    title: "File Upload Area",
                    msg: "File Uploaded!",
                    file: 'uploads/${req.file.filename}'
                });
            }
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    
    console.log("Running on port 3000...")
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I'm trying to figure out exactly what the problem is you're seeing here, is it that the buttons are displaying the wrong routes?  Also, why do you have question marks in app.get("/:suburb?/:page?"

Comment: Hi Graham thanks for your response. The buttons are linked to the wrong url. I'm running from localhost, and whenever I click the "previous" or "next" buttons in my bootstrap pagination bar, instead of the target url showing something like: localhost/suburb/1 it's just suburb/1, how do I keep the localhost in there?

Comment: You don't need to have the server's name included in a link, all browsers know how to translate links relative to the current page so that's not an issue.  Your code will produce routes that are like '/suburb/1' which should work just fine.  Is there an error when you click on the next/previous buttons when browsing with suburbs?